# Upgrading already published app's API from 1.6 to 2.1?

Tags: android

I have a mildly successful app that targets Android 1.6 and am looking to upgrade the target API to 2.1 in order to include more features.

What will happen to those still using android 1.6? Will they just not see the update? I'd love to be able to check which api the user is using and implement code based on that within the same app.

It's a paid app so making a new separate version is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you write the new version of your app.

If the new features have equivalents in 1.6, just that new APIs are used, you may be in the "old Contacts vs new Contacts API" boat. See [Using the Contacts API](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/contacts.html) and search for 'legacy'.

Search the above link for `Supporting the old and new APIs in the same application` for sample code to select APIs based on current OS version.

If you can code your app so it still runs on 1.6 and newer OSes even though you use new APIs, then you'll need to modify the `uses-sdk` element in the `AndroidManifest.xml` to tell Android you can handle the older OSes. See [AndroidManifest.xml  uses-sdk element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#min).

Answer (score 1):

Hey Dom Read this question it's the exact answer:

[What if I want to release an update with higher minSDK than the one on the market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968988/what-if-i-want-to-release-an-update-with-higher-minsdk-than-the-one-on-the-market/4969477#4969477)

Yes you can check the API code and use reflection to only allow methods to work for 2.1, see above link

Comment: thanks! tried searching so many keywords and forgot to try minSDK