# Downloading files in API <9

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, android-2.3-gingerbread

I just realized that my app, with over 300 users still using an Android version under Gingerbread, is having issues for them because they dont have the DownloadManager that was introduced in API 9 (2.3). Is there a compatibility library or something that I can use or is my best best just to use an asyncTask to download the files manually?

Comment: You can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968988/what-if-i-want-to-release-an-update-with-higher-minsdk-than-the-one-on-the-marke/4969477#4969477

Comment: No, I know how to check and see if that api is available, I just need to know what the best way to download a file on froyo is. Whether its possible to use the download manager via reflection, if there's a compatibility library to be used, or if I'm out of luck and will have to do it manually.

Comment: No there is no compatibility library option for this. Reflection is your answer.

Comment: No, absolutely **do not use reflection**. Your app will crash or the download will simply not execute, depending on how you handle the exceptions it will invariably throw on devices running API level 8 or older.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Is there a compatibility library or something that I can use

No, `DownloadManager` is not in the Android Support package. I took a look at making my own backport a while ago and concluded that it was *way* too complicated, since it has its own content provider and whatnot.

> is my best best just to use an asyncTask to download the files manually?

If the files are large, I would consider an `IntentService` over an `AsyncTask`, so the download can be better decoupled from the UI. But, regardless, you do need to download it yourself.