# DownloadManager downloading files over 2.1 GB

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I am working on an app and one of the features I am working on is to download some binary files. Some of them are really big (more than several mega-bytes). Downloads are completing fine as long as the file size is less than 2 GB.

I got stuck on a file that is 3.2GB in that I get progress updates (I am pooling the DownloadManager for progress updates), but when the download completes, the file is not present on the target file path. Interrogating the `DownloadManager` for that download id, I get [`STATUS_FAILED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#STATUS_FAILED) and reason [`ERROR_UNKNOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#ERROR_UNKNOWN) - the favorite error details one will ever wish for!

What is weird is that this appears on most of the devices, but for some (like Samsung SG 4 Active OS 4.2.2 and LG Nexus 5 OS 4.4.2), it doesn't appear.

Doing some extra investigation, I found out that this seems to be a [bug in Android `DownloadManager` implementation](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41163). It seems Android implementation stores the download count as an int, but when that count goes above `Integer.MAX_VALUE` the download ends as failed.

I am thinking to replace the `DownloadManager` usage with a foreground service, but I wouldn't give up yet ....

Did you guys face this and if so, how did you fix it?
Is there any work-around to use `DownloadManager` in pre-4.2.2 so I can download more than 2.1 GB per file?

Comment: check out the Ion from Koush: https://github.com/koush/ion it's quite great and it might work well with large files

Comment: @josebama: is the actual download loosed from UI? I mean if the user rotates the device, exits from app and then re-enters, will the download continue and be consistent with the whole UI?

Comment: I can't confirm, but it is supposed to

Comment: Well, 2.1gb is close enough to 2^31. I can guess why

Comment: @taytay: To be rude: because of the wise guy that made the counter field `int` and not `long` in `DownloadManager` implementation!

Comment: When it goes up to 4GB, you might probably run into issues with the file system. As you should probably support downloading to the external card with such big files, it is likely that you're running into the 4GB size limit when the cards are FAT formatted.

Comment: @PMF: Can you please detail what do you mean by `4GB issue`?

Comment: Well, the FAT32 filesystem (which is still widely used, especially for SD-cards and other exchangeable media), doesn't support files larger than 4GB.

Comment: Why cant you implement your own http file downloader service.

Comment: Because the `DownloadManager` takes care for me on the following: resume the download when connectivity is restored, download over specific channel (WiFi or Mobile), continue the download if the application is killed.

Comment: Then make a custom version from the `DownloadManager` implementation itself. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3_r1/android/app/DownloadManager.java

Comment: @ShaktiThakran: The problem is not with the `DownloadManager` as `enqueue` method just enqueues the download request using a system `ContentProvider`. I believe the problem lies in the actual downloader component and I also believe that's a different process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To download such a large files, you need to download those in chunks. Either you can use any library that support HTTP range options to allow to pull down a single file in multiple pieces , supporting resume etc.

Or you can split your large file on your server then have a text file with MD5 hash of each file, when you first start to download then get the MD5 file once finish then check that hashes matches the downloaded pieces. If they do not then delete that piece and add it to queue of items to download.

Once all pieces downloaded and MD5 works, you can put the pieces back together as single file.

If you are thinking to download the file in the SD card then FAT32 is the default file system. There is a 4 GB per file limit with this file system.

Comment: You have summarized what all the others said so far :) But I don't think you have provided something new.

Comment: This is only way you can go through it, I did not read other answers yet so far. I don't think I copied them, simply whatever possible I have simply wrote those and I don't know why it seemed to you I have not provided something new.

Comment: Accepting this answer even though it doesn't actually answers it, because there is no plausible answer. In the end I wrote my own download manager, but this answer is as close as one can accept. Initially I wanted to accept the answer from `ksasq` but I wasn't able to verify it as I don't have a server that knows to handle chuncked content. The `Range` solution works for me since the server supports it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

From looking at the Android source code, it appears that this issue was resolved in JB-MR2.

It seems that the only way to work around this on older platform versions would be to modify the server such that it uses chunked transfer encoding[1] for these large resources. In that case, that Download Manager will ignore and not attempt to parse the Content-Length header.

[1] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding

Comment: Thanks for answering (+1), but as said, unfortunately this is not an option on server side. Anyway, I wonder if someone tried this approach and confirmed if it's working

Comment: This answer has 5 upvotes so far and no confirmation that this actually works. I don't have access to a server that supports chuncked content response in order to check it.

Answer (score 2):

There is one clear outcome of this:

*You can not fix the `DownloadManager`*. If it's a bug in it, it will be so. **Therefore, in short, No**, you can not workaround this issue using the `DownloadManager`. You could however workaround it using a server side approach that has been put into words in the other answers.

So, I think your simplest solution would be to force the minimum sdk level to JB-MR2 because @ksasq mentioned that this issue has been resolved.

If that is not plausible nor in your case possible, you can find the best file download library out there and create an interface similar to DownloadManager's for this library. Of course, this interface should be implemented to use the default DownloadManager for versions which do not have this bug and use the custom library for those which had this bug (and for files who cause the issue if possible).

Unfortunately, a search on google showed [yingyixu's android-download-manager](https://github.com/yingyixu/android-download-manager) last updated in 2012.

Another [unfortunate note about this topic by CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9967750/833622) simply verifies that there is no DownloadManager in google's support libraries. Worse is that the guy gave up the idea of implementing his own port becuase it was way too complicated. You can only hope that yingyixu's library or some other library you hopefully find is good enough.

Comment: The download is only one of the features of the app. I cannot set the minimum level to JB-MR2 because I'll lose the rest of the market share.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass this issue by splitting file into smaller zip files. Next step is to join them on target, I've found [->this<-](http://www.coderanch.com/t/473507/java-io/java/Splitting-zip-file-rejoining) that might help you. If you will not compress file (split only option) you should have good performance. Other issue is that you will need twice as much storage space. You can download smaller files, about 100MB, write it to joined buffer and remove form file-system, that will preserve space wasting.

Comment: Thanks for answering (+1), but this is not an option on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take the fixed version of [DownloadManager](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4_r1/android/app/DownloadManager.java/?v=source), change the package to your package structure and use this version instead of the system version. Eventually you need to import some classes from the original package `android.app`. Then register your implementation as a service.

Comment: The actual download is not made by DownloadManager; a system app does it on behalf of the caller app. To test this, start a download from a sample app, force close the app and when opening the Download Manager app you will see the download is in progress.